# `tokio::try_join!` on a vector of `JoinHandle`s

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

New to Rust. I want to wait for the following async tasks to finish:

```
let _ = tokio::try_join!(fetch_handle, evaluate_handles[0], evaluate_handles[1], evaluate_handles[2], evaluate_handles[3]);
```

Is there a way to do this without hard-coding each item in `evaluate_handles`? `evaluate_handles` is a `Vec<JoinHandle<()>>`, and `fetch_handle` is just a single `JoinHandle<()>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can use `TryJoinAll` to do `try_join!` on an iterator of tasks (futures):

```
use futures::future::TryJoinAll;
let join_evaluate_handles = evaluate_handles.into_iter().collect::<TryJoinAll<_>>();
```

In your case, all the join handles have the same type, so you could just construct an iterator that contains them all:

```
evaluate_handles.into_iter()
    .chain(once(fetch_handle))
    .collect::<TryJoinAll<_>>()
    .await
```

If they weren't the same type, you would combine `TryJoinAll` and `try_join!`:

```
try_join!(fetch_handle, join_evaluate_handles /* from above */)
```

---

Note, however, that I'm not sure it's super meaningful to use `try_join` here anyway. `try_join`'s main point is that it returns immediately if one of the futures errors. But your futures are `JoinHandle`s, and those only error when the spawned task panics: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2bcc30461dc6b8fd4a8687191343e770)
Now, panicking in a spawned future makes tokio print an ugly error message, and you want to avoid that in general. The only practical use-case for using `try_join` here I can think of is aborting your application if a panic happens somewhere. But I think there's less hassle-full ways of doing this.

---

One more note: If you're using `TryJoinAll` or `FuturesUnordered`, there's no real need to `tokio::spawn` your tasks in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by putting all of the `JoinHandle`s into a [`FuturesUnordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/futures_unordered/struct.FuturesUnordered.html) and then driving that to completion as a `Stream`:

```
use std::time::Duration;

use futures::{stream::FuturesUnordered, StreamExt};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let tasks = FuturesUnordered::new();

    for i in 0..10 {
        tasks.push(tokio::spawn(async move {
            println!("task {i} starting");
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
            println!("task {i} finished");
        }));
    }

    println!("joining tasks");

    tasks.for_each(|_| async {}).await;

    println!("joined all tasks");
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=18be3a0a1e27be0b4cc48a9e6472b125))

Note that you can `collect` into a `FuturesUnordered` so if you can express the tasks as an iterator of `JoinHandles` you can make the code a lot simpler.

```
use std::time::Duration;

use futures::{stream::FuturesUnordered, StreamExt};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let tasks: FuturesUnordered<_> = (0..10)
        .map(|i| {
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                println!("task {i} starting");
                tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
                println!("task {i} finished");
            })
        })
        .collect();

    println!("joining tasks");

    tasks.for_each(|_| async {}).await;

    println!("joined all tasks");
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bd0a3c7a8c7b4ab7d568d01a58361eb2))

Comment: That differs a bit from the behavior that @OP had: Consider [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e34ae6cb46223c3adef7680737de7c0e). `try_join` aborts when the first error is returned, `FuturesUnordered` waits for all. Also, since you're already spawning, there's really no need for `FuturesUnordered`, you could just await the join handles in a loop for the same result. (I also chuckled at the "a lot simpler" ;P)

Comment: Hm. I have to recant. The behavior difference exists, but it's irrelevant: The thing being joined are `JoinHandle`s, and those only `Err` when the spawned future panics, which @OP likely doesn't care about. (And my playground should have looked like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f7155eb63fe22ded4351ed7d5d7648f1) to demonstrate the difference.)

Comment: If they did care about panics or errors from the task itself it could be addressed using `try_for_each` instead of `for_each`. But it's also possible that delaying until all tasks are done is also important, so there's a few unknowns. Regardless, `FuturesUnordered` provides a foundation for addressing any combination of these use cases, even if there is a simpler way to express a few of them.

Comment: `try_for_each` is [not really obvious](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&edition=2021&gist=6e5b8b7a20b5ae5f64707db0255be655) to me (The fact that `FuturesUnordered` can [implement `TryStream`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/prelude/stream/trait.TryStream.html#implementors) surprised me, too). An [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&edition=2021&gist=efefc8a6fc0649ad7afc59f7c56e7186) like `while let Some(completed) = tasks.next().await { /* handle task results in order of completion */ }` might have explained the flexibility of `FuturesUnordered` better.

Comment: @Caesar I'm not sure what's not obvious about it. It returns a `Result` which you ignore (the compiler warns you about this too: `warning: unused Result that must be used`) so it's not surprising that joining all tasks appears to succeed even though one panicked. You need to handle the `Result` in some way, e.g.: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a5c82bd69cc2dc90760bf81793f13401

Comment: Oh, I hadn't even noticed that part. (I saw that it finished in a second and was happy with that.) No, what I found weird was the `|()| ready(Ok(()))`. I'm guessing that `try_for_each` discards the result (and short-circuits on `Err` before even calling the closure), and then hands the `()` from the `JoinHandle` to the closure, and all that closure can do is to say "yeah, I'm immediately happy with the task not panicking"? I.e., the thing that's being tried is not the closure, but the stream item. Maybe `try_collect::<()>()` would have expressed that less weirdly?

Comment: @Caesar It's actually both: the stream item _and_ the result from the closure can be `Err`, and if either are then `try_for_each` will ultimately fail. However, I think you are correct that `try_collect` might be a bit clearer in this case when there is no actual work to be done with each result.